# Break out of foreach loop, echo, then continue the foreach?

Tags: php, foreach

I have this little bit of script that just runs a query, retrieves all the categories in a database, and then lists them one on top of the other.

```
if ($all_categories) {
 foreach ($all_categories as $cid => $arr) {

 $sidebar .= '<a href="index.php?action=sort&cid=' . $cid . '">' . $arr['name'] . ' (' . $arr['count'] . ')</a><br />';
 }
}
} else {
$sidebar = 'There are no categories yet';
}
```

Basically, I need this code to loop through the first 10 results, then echo some HTML div and then pick back up off in the loop. I am however new and not sure how I would go about doing this. I was thinking of incorporating a counter but not sure if that would be the correct method.

Comment: Counter is a good option. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( $all_categories ) {
    $count = 1;

    foreach ( $all_categories as $cid => $arr ) {
        $sidebar .= '<a href="index.php?action=sort&cid=' . $cid . '">' . $arr['name'] . ' (' . $arr['count'] . ')</a><br />';

        if ( 10 == $count ) {
            $sidebar .= 'This code fires after the 10th result is displayed.';
        }

        $count++;
    }
} else {
    $sidebar = 'There are no categories yet';
}
```

Comment: $count > 0 && $count++ % 10 == 0
is better

Comment: The question refers to the first 10 results, not every 10 results.

Comment: its highy likely that he actually is talking about every 10th result, everything else wouldnt make much sense.

Comment: I need the $sidebar to take over the echo. So sidebar prints 10 categories, then sidebar prints div code, then sidebar finishes the categories. Also no, after the 10th result not every 10.

Comment: @user3858124 - I've updated the code to append to the sidebar variable instead of directly echo.

Comment: in that case your solution is flawed. Rethink your strategy, if you need to manually count your steps in the loop your data-source is incorrectly formed.